# Scheduling a SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqltransaction

what is the best way to schedule a SQL Job to run from (any date range) i.e. 15th to 18th every single month with no end date?

Thanks in advance.

john

Comment: Are you using SQL server management studio?

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 you can set the frequency to occur Monthly and have 3 or 4 individual schedules to occur on the 15th, 16th, 17th, and 18th day of each month. Similar to the below image.

[image]

Not the cleanest solution but it does work.

Comment: Ok that would be a slightly solution I guess as there is not way to do it in a single schedule. Noisily fact!